# Summarising after grouping using "rolling" groups

Tags: r

I want to obtain a column with the rolling income average for each age, but including the ages one year older and younger. For example, for age 42 and type 1, one would have to use all the income data that have ages 41,42 and 43 (if existing) for that type, and so on. I would like a systematic way of doing it.

Minimal data would be something like this:

```
income <- c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000)
age <- c(41, 42, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 47, 49, 50)
type <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(income, age, type))
```

I thought of using zoo's rollapply but that would be for the sequence of income variable observations, not for the values of one the grouping variables, which are the ones I want to "roll".

Sort of a `dplyr (group_by(type,age)) %>% summarize (avg=mean(income))`, but grouping age in a rolling way (age-1, age, age+1). The purpose is to smooth the mean income by age in overlapping intervals of three years. Of course income at the two ages in each of the tails of the age distribution would be less or no smoothed at all.

Thanks!!

P.S. The expected outcome would be this, I think (manual calculation):

```
> dfexpected
   age type mean_income
1   41    1        1500
2   42    1        1500
3   43    1        2000
4   44    1        6000
5   45    1        6000
6   46    1        7500
7   47    1        9000
8   48    1        9500
9   49    1       10500
10  50    1       10500
11  41    2        3000
12  42    2        3000
13  43    2        3500
14  44    2        4000
15  45    2        5500
16  46    2        7500
17  47    2        7500
18  48    2        8000
19  49    2          NA
20  50    2          NA
```

Note the mean income per (rolling) age and type is only NA if the income for that type in all three years around that age has all NA's. 
Even if the actual data for a given age is NA, if there is observations one year above of below, the mean would be calculated (ignoring NAs).

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(mean = rollmean(age, k = n()))`

Comment: The variable of interest is income, Akrun. Sorry it was perhaps not clear in the first version of the question, I edited.

Comment: if you change it to `rollmean(income, k  = n())` would that help

Comment: Not working, apparently. For the last two observations the mean should be 10.500, taking the average of 10.000 and 11.000 (both belong to the same type, and for age 49 one would roll over ages 48, 49 y 50 to get the income data, and for age 50 one would roll ages 49, 50 and 51... of course ignoring 51 which does not have data)

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(grp = rleid(type)) %>% mutate(mean = rollmean(income, k = n()))`

Comment: In my actual data I have many observations for each type and for each age.  I don't want to roll over the income, I need the mean income (by type) in rolling periods of three years of age. Thanks though!

Comment: sorry, it is not clear.  May be expected output would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sort of brute-force `tidyverse` approach.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(income =  c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000), 
                 age = c(41, 42, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 47, 49, 50),
                 type =  c(1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1))
```

Specify years included in each rolling average, here meaning "include the year prior, the year of, and the next year."

```
yr_range = c(-1:1)   # same as c(-1, 0, 1)
```

Make a copy of each row for each entry in `yr_range` using `tidyr::uncount`, then create a dummy `age_adj` that adjusts each row's age to move it into a bucket for summarization:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  uncount(length(yr_range)) %>%
  mutate(age_adj = rep(yr_range, length.out = n()),
         age_bucket  = age + age_adj) %>%
# At this point it looks like:
#   income age type age_adj age_bucket
#1    1000  41    1      -1         40
#2    1000  41    1       0         41  
#3    1000  41    1       1         42
#4    2000  42    2      -1         41   
#5    2000  42    2       0         42
#6    2000  42    2       1         43
  group_by(type, age_bucket) %>%
  summarize(income_mean = mean(income)) %>%
  # optional, to prune edge years beyond orig data
  filter(age_bucket >= min(df$age),
         age_bucket <= max(df$age))

> df2
# A tibble: 18 x 3
# Groups:   type [2]
    type age_bucket income_mean
   <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1     1         41        1500
 2     1         42        1500
 3     1         43        2000
 4     1         44        6000
 5     1         45        6000
 6     1         46        7000
 7     1         47        8000
 8     1         48        9000
 9     1         49       10500
10     1         50       10500
11     2         41        3000
12     2         42        3000
13     2         43        3500
14     2         44        4000
15     2         45        5500
16     2         46        8000
17     2         47        8000
18     2         48        9000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, brute force gets the job done ;) Could also just filter `age == age_bucket` to trim the bucket rows, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Create a type/age grid `g` and merge it with `df` giving `m`.  Then use `ave` to run `rollapply` by `type`:

```
library(zoo)

g <- expand.grid(type = unique(df$type), age = seq(min(df$age), max(df$age)))
m <- merge(g, df, all.x = TRUE)
roll <- function(x) rollapply(x, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE)
transform(m, avg = ave(income, type, FUN = roll))
```

giving:

```
   type age income   avg
1     1  41   1000  2000
2     1  42   3000  2000
3     1  43     NA  3000
4     1  44     NA  6000
5     1  45   6000  6000
6     1  46     NA  7000
7     1  47   8000  8000
8     1  48     NA  9000
9     1  49  10000 10500
10    1  50  11000 10500
11    2  41     NA  2000
12    2  42   2000  2000
13    2  43     NA  3000
14    2  44   4000  4000
15    2  45     NA  5500
16    2  46   7000  8000
17    2  47   9000  8000
18    2  48     NA  9000
19    2  49     NA   NaN
20    2  50     NA   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks so much, great answer!!